# How to define PyCharm-friendly value object in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm curious about good way to define value object in Python. Per Wikipedia: "[value object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) is a small object that represents a simple entity whose equality isn't based on identity: i.e. two value objects are equal when they have the same value, not necessarily being the same object". In Python that essentially means redefined `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods, as well as immutability.

Standard `namedtuple` seems like almost perfect solution with exception that they don't play well with modern Python IDE like PyCharm. I mean that IDE will not really provide any helpful insights about class defined as `namedtuple`. While it's possible to attach docstring to such class using trick like this:

```
class Point2D(namedtuple("Point2D", "x y")):
    """Class for immutable value objects"""
    pass
```

there's simply no place where to put description of constructor arguments and specify their types. PyCharm is smart enough to guess arguments for `Point2D` "constructor", but type-wise it's blind.

This code have some type information pushed in, but it's not very useful:

```
class Point2D(namedtuple("Point2D", "x y")):
    """Class for immutable value objects"""
    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        """
        :param x: X coordinate
        :type x: float

        :param y: Y coordinate
        :type y: float

        :rtype: Point2D
        """
        return super(Point2D, cls).__new__(cls, x, y)

point = Point2D(1.0, 2.0)
```

PyCharm will see types when constructing new objects, but will not grasp that point.x and point.y are floats, so would not not help to detect their misuse. And I also dislike the idea of redefining "magic" methods on routine basis.

So I'm looking for something that will be:

- just as easy to define as normal Python class or namedtuple
- provide value semantics (equality, hashes, immutability)
- easy to document in a way that will play nicely with IDE

Ideal solution could look like this:

```
class Point2D(ValueObject):
    """Class for immutable value objects"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """
        :param x: X coordinate
        :type x: float

        :param y: Y coordinate
        :type y: float
        """
        super(Point2D, self).__init__(cls, x, y)
```

Or that:

```
class Point2D(object):
    """Class for immutable value objects"""

    __metaclass__ = ValueObject

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """
        :param x: X coordinate
        :type x: float

        :param y: Y coordinate
        :type y: float
        """
        pass
```

I tried to find something like this but without success. I thought that it will be wise to ask for help before implementing it by myself.

UPDATE:
With help of user4815162342 I managed to come up with something that works. Here's the code:

```
class ValueObject(object):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __repr__(self):
        attrs = ' '.join('%s=%r' % (slot, getattr(self, slot)) for slot in self.__slots__)
        return '<%s %s>' % (type(self).__name__, attrs)

    def _vals(self):
        return tuple(getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ValueObject):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__slots__ == other.__slots__ and self._vals() == other._vals()

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._vals())

    def __getstate__(self):
        """
        Required to pickle classes with __slots__
        Must be consistent with __setstate__
        """
        return self._vals()

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        """
        Required to unpickle classes with __slots__
        Must be consistent with __getstate__
        """
        for slot, value in zip(self.__slots__, state):
            setattr(self, slot, value)
```

It's very far from an ideal solution. Class declaration looks like this:

```
class X(ValueObject):
    __slots__ = "a", "b", "c"

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        """
        :param a:
        :type a: int
        :param b:
        :type b: str
        :param c:
        :type c: unicode
        """
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

It's total FOUR times to list all attributes: in `__slots__`, in ctor arguments, in docstring and in ctor body. So far I have no idea how to make it less awkward.

Comment: Note that `namedtuple` has a primary purpose of providing both the tuple interface (indexing, unpacking), and attribute access. It was invented for backward-compatibility of functions that used to return tuples, such as `os.stat` or `time.gmtime`. It is likely not the optimal choice for a simple value type.

Comment: Regarding types: *PyCharm is smart enough to guess arguments for Point2D "constructor", but type-wise it's blind* Maybe you should be using a statically typed language? In Python it shouldn't be such a big deal that an IDE is blind about types.

Comment: Well, `namedtuple` almost do the right job for me. It's definitely more then simple value object, but I can live with it.

As for using statically typed language, I wish I could. But I have a Python project on hands and looking for a way to make development more comfortable. And PyCharm already does very good job for inferring type of variables using docstrings.

Answer (score 6):

### New in version 3.5: The `typing` module and `NamedTuple`

In version 3.5, the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module has been added, in it, you will find a class that perfectly fits your needs.

#### The new [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)

It works just as you'd expect:

- Simple type definition:

  ```
  from typing import NamedTuple
  class DownloadableFile(NamedTuple):
      file_path: str
      download_url: str
  ```
- Recognized in PyCharm:

  [image: PyCharm completion]
  [image: PyCharm type detection]

---

**Note**:
As of today, the API is still in a [provisional stage](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-provisional-api). It means it isn't guaranteed to be backwards compatible when new version is released. Changes to the interface though are not expected. My personal take on it is: given the simplicity of the design, if change there is, I am sure it will be an easy refactor ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your requirements, although carefully expressed, are not quite clear to me, partly because I don't use the PyCharm GUI. But here is an attempt:

```
class ValueObject(object):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __init__(self, *vals):
        if len(vals) != len(self.__slots__):
            raise TypeError, "%s.__init__ accepts %d arguments, got %d" \
                % (type(self).__name__, len(self.__slots__), len(vals))
        for slot, val in zip(self.__slots__, vals):
            super(ValueObject, self).__setattr__(slot, val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('<%s[0x%x] %s>'
                % (type(self).__name__, id(self),
                   ' '.join('%s=%r' % (slot, getattr(self, slot))
                            for slot in self.__slots__)))

    def _vals(self):
        return tuple(getattr(self, slot) for slot in self.__slots__)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, ValueObject):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__slots__ == other.__slots__ and self._vals() == other._vals()

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._vals())

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if attr in self.__slots__:
            raise AttributeError, "%s slot '%s' is read-only" % (type(self).__name__, attr)
        super(ValueObject, self).__setattr__(attr, val)
```

Usage is like this:

```
class X(ValueObject):
  __slots__ = 'a', 'b'
```

This gets you a concrete value class with two read-only slots and an autogenerated constructor, `__eq__`, and `__hash__`. For example:

```
>>> x = X(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 5, in __init__
TypeError: X.__init__ accepts 2 arguments, got 3
>>> x = X(1.0, 2.0)
>>> x
<X[0x4440a50] a=1.0 b=2.0>
>>> x.a
1.0
>>> x.b
2.0
>>> x.a = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 32, in __setattr__
AttributeError: X slot 'a' is read-only
>>> x.c = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 33, in __setattr__
AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'c'
>>> dir(x)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_vals', 'a', 'b']
>>> x == X(1.0, 2.0)
True
>>> x == X(1.0, 3.0)
False
>>> hash(x)
3713081631934410656
>>> hash(X(1.0, 2.0))
3713081631934410656
>>> hash(X(1.0, 3.0))
3713081631933328131
```

If you want, you can define your own `__init__` with the docstring that (presumably) provides your IDE with type annotation hints.

Comment: I played with this solution for some time. It grasps semantics of value object precisely, but has same troubles with type inference as `namedtuple`. Adding `__init__` doesn't really help: without "magical" string like `self.a = a` PyCharm has no idea that it should link type declaration of an argument to an object attribute. I used your code to build something that will work for me, but it's far from perfect. I'm attaching it as update to original question now.

Answer (score 3):

An update solution:

Since python 3.7 there is a new built in module called `dataclasses` which has the `dataclass` class in it.

Pycharm supports it and knows how to work with it.

It is a perfect fit for a value object, since it already defines a lot of what you would define for a value object and the syntax is really short:

- **repr**
- **eq**
- making the class immutable by passing `Frozen=True`

example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Point2D:
    x: float
    y: float
```

There are differences between `NamedTuple` and `Dataclasses` which most notably one is based on a tuple and the other one on a dict.

In my opinion, the `dataclass` is the best code generator ATM to create a value object.

For more info, continue with python's [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) about how to use a `dataclass`.